# How to run command by nodejs script

Tags: javascript, node.js

H,
I am trying to install one module by scripting method but i do not know how to install that by node scripting language or if you have any idea please share with me.

```
if(filename==".tgz"){

//How to run this command?
"npm install --save ../test/datemodule.tgz"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) API.

```
if (filename === ".tgz") {
  const { exec } = require("child_process");
  exec("npm install --save ../test/datemodule.tgz");
}
```

Comment: Tried but not working